# How can I transfer files from Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS to Windows 10 automatically?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, automation, ubuntu-20.04

I have a web site on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and I need to copy its database backups (created with CronJobs) to a couple of other Windows 10 machines automatically. The Ubuntu Server itself sits on the Windows 10 Hyper-V virtual machine.

How can that be done?

I'm not a very experienced Linux user, so I would appreciate if somebody could explain this to me in details.

Comment: I maintain a system that does this simply by mounting a Windows SMB share and copying with a shell script called by a cron job. Specifics will vary in your case of course but that may be a big-picture approach to consider.

Comment: Job to (1) Map drive  (smb://drive/folder with authentication (2) copy DB and (3) disconnect drive

Comment: I don't really understand this. I would prefer a detailed explanation if that's possible.